# Slavoj Zizek and jouissance

Tags: hegel, psychoanalysis

Can anyone explain to me what jouissance mean in Slavoj Zizek's philosophy? I understand Lacan's term, but I am having a hard time understanding Slavoj Zizek's jouissance.

More specifically, how does jouissance relate to political power?

Comment: Zizek's notion *is* Lacan's, largely -- could you please be a bit more specific with regards to the particular challenge you're encountering with this idea?

Comment: Closing for the time being pending further development of the concern

Answer (score 1):

A good resource for Zizek material is his lectures at the the European Graduate school, this http://www.egs.edu/faculty/slavoj-zizek/videos/enjoyment-as-a-political-factor/ for example is related .. One dimension of jouissance which Zizek focuses on is its complicity with the superego, meaning its expression is conditioned by internalized familial and social injunctions, and is by these means related to capitalism